# An add-for visual studio 2013 that can trigger the run/debug of some google tests

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, add-in, googletest

I have a huge visual studio 2013 solution in c++, containing three types of projects : one console project that handles google tests, dll projects, and a static library project for the google test static libraries.

Often when I code and run the all the google tests, some tests happen to fail, and I have to debug them. To do this, I have to run the google test executable with a special option telling just to run the special test I want to debug etc...

After some time, it starts to be boring. That's why I have the following idea : I would like to have, when right-clicking in the middle of a test case, one more line at the end of the window appearing in visual studio 2013 (when I right-click) called for instance "debug this test" that would trigger the debug of this test.

I really didn't know the technology adequate to do this, but digging a bit brought me in the "visual studio 2013 add-ins" field, which is the right technology to achieve want I'd like to do. (To have when right-clicking in the middle of a test case in the c++ code, one more line at the end of the window appearing in visual studio 2013 (when I right-click) called for instance "debug this test" that would trigger the debug of this test.)

Is there any "examples" somewhere that I could inspire myself of ? Or could anyone guide me on the subject ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't help VS2013 unfortunately. My professional career skipped that one.

However Visual Studio 2015 does give this functionality out of the box.

[image]

I'm sure there are some tools that can do this in VS2013, but I don't think its default?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx

EDIT. Apparently it is there is VS2013 and VS2012?

Comment: Good idea, but the google test project my tests are in is not a visual studio test project, but a simple win32 c++ console project linking to google test static libraries...

Comment: My test projects are in my solution. I create a separate build configuration (Release/Debug/Test) and turn off the test project in Release and Debug (so its not compiled as a debug or release). This way all your code can be managed in one place and I can explicitly compile the test project to see my results in the TestExplorer? Especially since these tests are relevant to the code in this solution/project. It's nice and simple this way and other than writing the tests in the first place, I never need to worry about them unless I see a big red circle in there ;)

Comment: Then as part of CI, Jenkins will build the solution with the 'Test Configuration' and simply run the compiled results. This of course only works because the code is in the TestProject rather than dynamically or statically linked. Even then the configuration can be setup to build what is needed (be it static or dynamic libs). Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, the idea is in my case especially to systematically build the tests in dbg/rel modes, so that a new configuration is not optimal. Note the "what I want to do" bit in my question.